# Mapping two different JSON's field names to one POJO property

Tags: json, jackson

I have two `JSON` strings with the same format from different sources, but one has camelcase, one has snakecase, how can I map them to the same `POJO` field using `Jackson`?
For example:

```
{ "fieldName": "abcd"}
```

and

```
{ "field_name": "abcd"}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should create two setter methods:

```
class Entity {

    private String fieldName;

    public String getFieldName() {
        return fieldName;
    }

    public void setFieldName(String fieldName) {
        this.fieldName = fieldName;
    }

    public void setField_name(String field_name) {
        this.fieldName = field_name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `@JsonCreator` annotation to specify how to construct your object.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class MyPojo {
    private final String fieldName;

    // Jackson version
    @JsonCreator
    public static MyPojo of(
            @JsonProperty("field_name") final String fieldName1,
            @JsonProperty("fieldName") final String fieldName2) {
        final String name = fieldName1 != null ? fieldName1 : fieldName2;
        return of(name);
    }

    // Programmatic version that you can use from code
    public static MyPojo of(
            @JsonProperty("fieldName") final String fieldName) {
        return new MyPojo(fieldName);
    }

    private MyPojo(final String fieldName) {
        this.fieldName = fieldName;
    }

    public String fieldName() {
        return fieldName;
    }
}
```

Your *POJO* will be neat and clean (without duplicate fields) and the creation-code is separated nicely.